# Array referencing an object in a different array

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, object

I have a list of trucks listed below. I also have a list of people also listed below. I want the second person (dondi) to be the owner of the Buttermilk Truck, but I don't know how to reference that in the attribute personsTruck. Any ideas?

```
 listTrucks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
               [Truck truckWithCuisine:@"American Cuisine" name:@"Buttermilk Truck" menu:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/Steve/Desktop/Truck Tracker App/Truck Tracker App/Buttermilk Truck Menu.tiff"] latitude: [NSNumber numberWithDouble: 0.1] longitude: [NSNumber numberWithDouble: 0.1]schedule:@"7/15/12"],


 listUsers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
             [Person personWithEmail:@"stephen" password:@"test" type:@"Eater" userFavoritesList:nil, personsTruck:nil],
             [Person personWithEmail:@"dondi" password:@"test" type:@"Owner" userFavoritesList:favoritedTrucks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], personsTruck:listTrucks.],
              nil];
 selectedPerson = nil;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `listUsers` store `personsTruck = 0`. It means first element at array `listTrucks`. To get value from `listTrucks` user `objectAtIndex:` 0 (personsTruck).

Answer (score 0):

Wether you know the owner of the truck, i mean is it static?

if yes you can go for this..

You can maintain the owner's name in trucks list by adding an index value of the users list in the Truck object, which gives the reference to users list.

Comment: Well when people register they choose either owner or what I call eater. If they are an owner they register their truck. I haven't gotten that far in the process, but for now I just wanted the owner of a certain truck to be able to edit its attributes. How would I got about adding this index value?

Comment: have one more NSUInteger value in Truck class, assign the index value of users list.